# How to ignore everything in a directory except one file

Tags: git

Repo structure:

```
.gitignore
file1
file2
dir/
    file3
    <stuff>
```

I want to ignore everything inside `dir` except file 3. Here's what I have in my `.gitignore` file:

```
dir/*
!dir/file3
```

But this doesn't seem to work. `git` still tries to index everything in `dir`. How do I fix this?

**UPDATE** - Fixed after deleting the old .gitignore file, and making a new one. The new one was *not* made using `> .gitignore`.

Comment: It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. [Source](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: @Alex.S Yes it is possible, you can `add -f` to force it to be tracked

Comment: The last sentence is a bit unclear. Does it mean your second code block worked after generating your `.gitignore` file differently?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund Yeah exactly.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The right way to do it is:

```
!dir
dir/*
!dir/file3
```

Note that there are other solutions, such as creating a local `.gitignore` file in `dir/`, which will take precedence over the previous one.

Curiously, I also tried your solution, and

```
dir/*
!dir/file3
```

Seems to work for me. If someone could comment on this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The second one works because dir/ is not ignored. Only dir content. And you can exclude (un-ignore) a file whose folder is not ignored.

Comment: I edited that doc back in the days: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/2697. Since then, subsequent edits were... not so accurate.

Comment: Ok, I have a more accurate picture of what's happening here, then. I might submit an edit in a few hours (~5), but feel free to do so in the mean time. It's a shame that such "vandalism" goes trough. I am sure the editors didn't really mean to add invalid information, but reviewers should probably check it more carefully, at least trying the solutions. I can't say how much I am pissed. Documentation _should_ be accurate, that's what it's for.

Comment: A few more questions, then: what is your git version? I suppose you are using it from the command line? And did you try putting a .gitignore file in the subdirectory?

Comment: Very sorry for replying so late. The version of git I'm using is 2.9.2.windows.1. Yes, from the command line. I use Powershell. So it does work now. I deleted the .gitignore file and made the same one again, except that I didn't make the new one using `> .gitignore`.

Comment: Might be related to line endings, that was one of my ideas. I have no idea how powershell handles those,  but I am pretty sure git requires CR and not CRLF, unless explicitly configured to.

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me:

```
!/dir/
/dir/*
!/dir/file3
```

Comment: Isn't the first line redundant?